# asp mvc implement search and Insert together

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm going to implement a Messaging system, in which user can find his contacts and send a message to them.
What I did : I have a form for searching contacts and showing result to sender(result are list of contacts), then another form to write message and send, but **How can send Message to those Contacts who already selected by sender** ?
My code for searching :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("FindContact", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "Result", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { id = "formfindContact" }))
                { 
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
     @Html.DropDownList("StateID", (ViewBag.States as SelectList), "States ...", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })

    @Html.DropDownList("CityID", (ViewBag.Cities as SelectList), new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })

    @Html.TextBox("PersonName", "", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
    @Html.TextBox("PersonCode", "", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="ُSearch" ></button>
    }


                <div id="Result">
                    @Html.Partial("_ContactList",new List<ContactResult>())
                </div>
```

And here codes for Sending (both codes are in a same view):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendMessage", "Messages", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formSendMessage" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextBox("Title", "", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
@Html.TextBox("Body", "", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
@Html.TextBox("Regards", "", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
 <a id="btnSend" href="#" class="btn btn-success" >Send</a>
}
```

My @model is List of messages to show in a table
Any Idea on Sending message with selected contacts list??

Comment: When you say _"already selected by sender"_, do you mean all contacts returned by `Ajax.BeginForm` or does the partial include checkboxes or some other method to select only some to send the message to.

Comment: @StephenMuecke; Actually in "FindContact" form, sender finds and sees every receiver he selected according to his search parameters

Comment: The partial could include the `SendMessage` form (rather than it being in the main view) and within the `<form>` tags include hidden inputs for the contact ID's so they post back as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you dont prowided code for _ContactList or FindContact views so i can suggest this:

In search resultring view you can add checkboxes with contact ID in value attribute, while checking them some JS code will update hidden input in formSendMessage. So when you post your message on controller you should receive selected id in form of, for example, comma separated string.

Just add to formSendMessage this:

```
@Html.Heddien("SelectedContactsId")
```

And some jQuery example:

```
$("#Result input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){ })
{
    var checkedIds= [];
    $('#Result input[type='checkbox'] :checked').each(function() {
        checkedIds.push($(this).val());
    });
    $("#SelectedContactsId").val(checkedIds.join(","));
}
```

Comment: My FindContact form has 4 properties : (StateID,CityID,PersonName,PersonCode), and SendMessage form has 3 propertis for posting (Title,Body,Regards). How can I send all these properties together? That's nice job, let me try

Comment: Your findContact is used just to FIND contacts, not to send it together with SendMessage. As i can see you use Ajax.BeginForm, so it should populate results in div with id Result. Here is my mistake, you should list for events in this container. Updated an ansver.